# Magento Cart Page Form Actions Blank

Tags: php, forms, magento, cloudways

The discount coupon form action and the main cart form action are blank/empty - so the forms don't submit properly.

rwd package with custom theme

checkout/cart.phtml
checkout/cart/coupon.phtml

are both overridden in the custom theme, but only text has been added and buttons re-arranged, nothing more.

If I remove those from the theme, the form actions output properly and forms work, if I put back problem recurs.

I've tried disabling/clearing cache.
Doesn't happen on local development environment, only happens on Cloudways server. Varnish is disabled on the server. Varnish extension is disabled as well.

Ideas welcome - thank you.

Comment: more info - created a another theme under rwd called test (rwd/test) with nothing in it except for the checkout/cart.phtml file and still having the same issue.

Comment: The solution was that the magento 1.9.1.1 template files differed from 1.9.2 . in the earlier version there was no method getFormActionUrl in the block checkout/cart hence it wasn't working in the tpl file - my local is 1.9.2 and server is 1.9.1.1

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that the magento 1.9.1.1 template files differed from 1.9.2 . in the earlier version there was no method getFormActionUrl in the block checkout/cart hence it wasn't working in the tpl file - my local is 1.9.2 and server is 1.9.1.1